# How to match the array keys and insert the values in new array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, array-key

I've an array called `$transaction_count` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_status] => success
            [StatusCount] => 25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_status] => inprocess
            [StatusCount] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
            [StatusCount] => 66
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [transaction_status] => fail
            [StatusCount] => 0
        )    
)
```

The above array gets generated dynamically so the array keys i.e.0,1,2,3 can be changed based on a query fired. That is the array could take following form or any other form too:

```
Array
    (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [transaction_status] => inprocess
                [StatusCount] => 5
            )


        [1] => Array
            (
                [transaction_status] => fail
                [StatusCount] => 0
            )    
    )
```

Now I want to set the following four variable values based on a condition.

```
$success_transaction_count, $inprocess_transaction_count, $cancelled_transaction_count, $failed_transaction_count
```

For example if the array `$transaction_count` is as below:

```
Array
        (

        [0] => Array
            (
                [transaction_status] => fail
                [StatusCount] => 10

            )


        [1] => Array
            (
               [transaction_status] => cancelled
               [StatusCount] => 25
            )    
    )
```

So in above case the values should get set as follows:

```
$failed_transaction_count = 10

$cancelled_transaction_count = 25
```

and other two variables should not get set as there are no matcing keys are present.

How should I set the values of variables properly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
$success_transaction_count=0;
$inprocess_transaction_count=0;
$cancelled_transaction_count=0;
$failed_transaction_count=0;

foreach($$transaction_count as $arr)
{
    if($arr['transaction_status']=='success')
    {
        $success_transaction_count += $arr['StatusCount'];
    }
    else if($arr['transaction_status']=='inprocess')
    {
        $inprocess_transaction_count += $arr['StatusCount'];
    }
    else if($arr['transaction_status']=='cancelled')
    {
        $cancelled_transaction_count += $arr['StatusCount'];
    }
    else if($arr['transaction_status']=='fail')
    {
        $failed_transaction_count += $arr['StatusCount'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not downvote you, but still I think this answer is suboptimal. You could easily factor the code, and use a function instead of putting all this glob of code at toplevel. Anyway, the OP seems to have grabbed his answer and scampered off, so this is not terribly important.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want correctly, this might work:

```
$transaction_count = array(
    array ("transaction_status" => "failed", "StatusCount" => 10),
    array ("transaction_status" => "cancelled", "StatusCount" => 25));

function set_counts ($input)
{
    foreach ($input as $pair)
    {
        // get back count for a given type
        $type = $pair["transaction_status"];
        $count = $pair["StatusCount"];

        // set the corresponding variable
        $var_name = $type."_transaction_count";
        global $$var_name;
        $$var_name = $count;
    }
}

set_counts ($transaction_count);

foreach (array("success", "inprocess",  "cancelled",  "failed") as $type)
{
    $var_name = $type."_transaction_count";
    $value = isset($$var_name) ? $$var_name : "not set";
    echo "$var_name: $value<br>";
}
```

output:

```
success_transaction_count: not set
inprocess_transaction_count: not set
cancelled_transaction_count: 25
failed_transaction_count: 10
```

Note that I would rather have all status counts set (i.e. the ones not explicitely counted set to 0 instead of left undefined), but I suppose you have your reasons.